# Is it possible to use a NetTopologySuite Point in a uniqueness key constraint using entity framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, nettopologysuite

I'm building an API using .net core and entity framework core with `NetTopologySuite.Core` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.NetTopologySuite`.

I have a use case where I want to store a set of geo locations that together builds up a net. I want to have multiple nets, so I have also added a `NetId` representing the different nets.

The `Location` property is of type `NetTopologySuite.Geometries.Point`.

To make sure the same `Point` do not get added two times for the same net, I would like to use the combination of `Point` and `NetId` as a unique key constraint.

I have tried to do it like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<NetLocation>().HasIndex(m => new { m.NetId, m.Point}).IsUnique();
```

When starting my application I get this error:

```
Column 'Location' in table 'MyTable' is of a type that is invalid for use as a key column in an index or statistics.
```

How can I make sure that the exact same location not get added twice to the same net?

Comment: Why don't you do a check, if a Point exists for a given NetId and than make the insert?

Comment: Such Point is mapped to the special spatial column type (geography) on sql server, and only special spatial index can be created on it. As far as I know, EF doesn't support spatial indexes (their creation has different syntax from regular indexes), and also - you cannot create spatial index on multiple columns anyway (not to mention one of those columns is not spatial).

Answer (score 0):

With SQL Server it's possible to add computed columns, PointLat = "Point.Lat" and PointLong = "Point.Long", and then use them in the index

```
modelBuilder.Entity<NetLocation>().HasIndex(m => new { m.NetId, m.PointLat, m.PointLong }).IsUnique();
```

Should work, but untested. Don't know about other providers, but they probably have similar `geography` support.